# A la hora de mandar una consulta de tipo insert into me sale el siguiente error: Undefined array key

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

Hola estoy implementando un FullCalendar con ajax, pero me da el siguiente error a la hora de insertar con ajax, y no consigo entender por que Gracias de antemano.

***Código Form***

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../../conexion_de_bbdd/config_bd.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION["usuario"])) {
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  header("Location: ../../../area_no_permitida/restringida.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <!-- <script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../eventos/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>

  <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
  <!-- idioma para el calendario en español -->
  <script src='locale/es.js'></script>

  <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />

  <!-- Estilos personalizados -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../front_end/font_awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../front_end/style.css">
  <script src="../eventos/js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../eventos/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]; ?>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Eventos
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="../../../panel_admin/admin.php">
                <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Panel de Administrador</a>

              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="../../cerrar_sesion/cerrar_sesion.php">
                Cerrar Sessión
                <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="text-center eventos">Eventos</h1>
        <!-- div que contiene el calendario de eventos -->
        <div id="calendario-custom"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#calendario-custom').fullCalendar({
        header: {
          left: 'today,prev,next,Miboton',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agendaWeek,agendaDay '
        },
        customButtons: { // abre customButtons
          Miboton: { // abre miboton
            text: "boton 1",
            click: function() {
              alert("acción del botón");
            }
          } // cierra miboton
        }, // cierra customButtons
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
          // alert("valor seleccionado : " + date.format()); //muestra la información del dia seleccionado.
          // alert("Vista actual : " + view.name); //puede ser dia mes o año
          // $(this).css('background-color', 'red'); //se colorea por que usa la palabra this al objeto.
          $('#fecha').val(date.format());
          $("#ModalEventos").modal(); //llama ala instrucción delmodal con su id de ejemplo
        },
        /*
          events : recupero el archivo de manera, local, y en forma de arrays para hacer la consulta
          desde la base de datos, ya preparada en el archivo.
        */
        events: 'http://localhost/aplicacion/back_end/panel_admin/eventos/recuperar-datos-json.php',

        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) { //evento cuando el usuario hace clic para verlo
          //Recupera la información del id_eventos (pk de la tabla)
          $('#title').val(calEvent.title);
          $('#id_usuarios').val(calEvent.id_usuarios);
          //Recupera la información del titulo
          $('#tituloEvento').html(calEvent.title);
          //Recupera la información de la descripción
          $('#descripcion').val(calEvent.descripcion);

          FechaHora = calEvent.start._i.split(" ");
          $('#fecha').val(FechaHora[0]);
          $('#hora').val(FechaHora[1]);

          $("#ModalEventos").modal();
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

  <!-- Modal (Agregar, Modificar y Eliminar) -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEventos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <!-- Coge el valor del titulo  -->
          <h5 class="modal-title titulo-modal-evento" id="tituloEvento"></h5>

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div>
            id_usuarios : <input type="text" id="id_usuarios" name="id_usuarios"><br>
            Título : <input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br>
            Fecha : <input type="text" id="fecha" name="fecha"><br>
            Hora : <input type="text" id="hora" name="hora" value="10:30"><br>
            usuario :
            <select name="selectUsuarios" id="selectUsuarios" class="col-sm-6 custom-control-desplegable"><br>
              <option value="" selected="selected">Selecciona un usuario</option>
              <?php
              $query_usuarios = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
              $usuarios = $query_usuarios->fetchAll();

              foreach ($usuarios as $fila_usuarios) {
              ?>
                <option value="<?= $fila_usuarios["id_usuarios"] ?>" <?php {
                                                                              echo ' selected="selected"';
                                                                            } ?>>
                  <?= $fila_usuarios["nombre"] ?>
                </option>
              <?php
              }
              ?>
            </select><br> 

            Descripcion : <textarea type="text" id="txtDescripcion" name="descripcion" rows="3"></textarea><br />
            Color : <input type="color" id="txtColor" value="#ff0000" name="color">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button type="button botones-modal-evento" id="btnAgregar" class="btn btn-success">
            Agregar
            <i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>

          <button type="button botones-modal-evento" class="btn btn-warning">
            Modificar
            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>

          <button type="button botones-modal-evento" class="btn btn-danger">
            Borrar
            <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>

          <button type="button botones-modal-evento" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
            Cancelar
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer style="background-color: #ffede7;" id="bajar-footer-panel-eventos">
    <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
      © 2020 Copyright:
      <a class="text-dark" href="#porftolio">D.Milanés</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->
  </footer>
  <!-- clic para el boton agregar del modal -->
  <script>
    var NuevoEvento;
    $('#btnAgregar').click(function() { //Cuando el usuario presiona el botón agrega la información
      ObtenerDatosDeLaInterfaz();
      EnviarInformacion('agregar',NuevoEvento);
    });

    function ObtenerDatosDeLaInterfaz() {
      var NuevoEvento = {
        id_usuarios: $('#id_usuarios').val(),
        selectUsuarios: $('#selectUsuarios').val(),
        //Mostrar la información del evento en los inputs
        title: $('#title').val(),
        start: $('#fecha').val() + " " + $('#hora').val(),
        end: $('#fecha').val() + " " + $('#hora').val(),
        color: $('#color').val(),
        textColor: "#FFFFFF" ,//Color por defecto que agregara el boton agregar
        descripcion: $('#descripcion').val()
       
      };
    }
    function EnviarInformacion(accion,objEvento){
      $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url: 'recuperar-datos-json.php?accion='+accion,
          data: objEvento,
          success:function(msg){
            if(msg){
              $('#calendario-custom').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
              $("#ModalEventos").modal('toggle');
              console.log(msg);
            }
          },
          error:function(){
            alert("hay un error..");
          }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>


</html>
```

***Código POST***

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once '../../conexion_de_bbdd/config_bd.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION["usuario"])) {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    header("Location: ../../../area_no_permitida/restringida.php");
}

$accion = (isset($_GET['accion'])) ? $_GET['accion'] : 'leer';
switch ($accion) {
    case 'agregar':
        # instrucción de agregado
        /*INSERT INTO `eventos` (`id_eventos`, `id_usuarios`, `title`, `start`, `end`, `color`, `textColor`, `descripcion`) 
        VALUES (NULL, '1', 'Evento de testeo', '2021-11-06 00:40:38.000000', '2021-11-06 00:40:38.000000', 'white', 'black', 'Evento de testeo');*/
       
        $sentenciaSQL = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO eventos (id_usuarios,title,start,end,color,textColor,descripcion)
        VALUES (:id_usuarios,:title,:start,:end,:color,:textColor,:descripcion);");
        $respuesta = $sentenciaSQL->execute(array(
        "selectUsuarios" => $_POST['selectUsuarios'],
        "title" => $_POST['title'],
        "start" => $_POST['start'],
        "end" => $_POST['end'],
        "color" => $_POST['color'],
        "textColor" => $_POST['textColor'],
        "descripcion" => $_POST['descripcion']
        ));
        /*
            "id_usuarios" => 1,
            "title" => "Evento prueba",
            "start" => "2021-11-07 00:40:38.000000",
            "end" => "2021-11-07 00:40:38.000000",
            "color" => "white",
            "textColor" => "black",
            "descripcion" => "asda"
        */

        //echo json_encode($result);
        //var_dump($result);
        $sentenciaSQL->debugDumpParams();
        //var_dump($respuesta);
      
        
        break;

    case 'eliminar':
        # instruccion de eliminar
        echo "instrucción eliminar";
        break;
    case 'modificar':
        echo "instrucción moddificar";

        break;

    default:
    # valores por defecto
    $nombreUsuarios = $_SESSION["usuario"];
    $sentenciaSQL = $bd->prepare("SELECT * 
    FROM eventos INNER JOIN usuarios as usuarios ON usuarios.id_usuarios = eventos.id_usuarios WHERE nombre = :nombre; 
        ");
        /*SELECT id_eventos,title,start,end,color,textColor,descripcion FROM eventos  
        INNER JOIN usuarios as usuarios ON usuarios.id_usuarios = eventos.id_eventos solo saca un registro hay que igualarlo con su fk para 
        que salgan todos
           */
        //SELECT * FROM eventos INNER JOIN usuarios as usuarios ON usuarios.id_usuarios = usuarios.id_usuarios WHERE nombre = 'David'; 
    $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":nombre", $nombreUsuarios);
    $sentenciaSQL->execute();

    $respuesta = $sentenciaSQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($respuesta);
        

        /*if($resultado_de_eventos == true){
            var_dump($resultado_de_eventos);
        echo "<br>";
            var_dump($eventos);
        }*/

        break;
}


?>
```

***El error al apretar el btnAgregar***

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "selectUsuarios" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\eventos\recuperar-datos-json.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "title" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\eventos\recuperar-datos-json.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "start" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\eventos\recuperar-datos-json.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "end" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\eventos\recuperar-datos-json.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "color" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\eventos\recuperar-datos-json.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "textColor" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\eventos\recuperar-datos-json.php</b> on line <b>26</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "descripcion" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\eventos\recuperar-datos-json.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\eventos\recuperar-datos-json.php:27
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\eventos\recuperar-datos-json.php(27): PDOStatement-&gt;execute(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\back_end\panel_admin\eventos\recuperar-datos-json.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />
eventos.php:222:23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que como en ObtenerDatosDeLaInterfaz() antepones var a NuevoEvento, lo que estás haciendo es declarar una variable dentro del entorno de esa función, de forma que no estás asignando nada a la var NuevoEvento que tienes fuera y que se supone que quieres usar como global.

Yo lo que haría sería que ObtenerDatosDeLaInterfaz() devuelva el NuevoEvento que crea, y se lo asigne al NuevoEvento de fuera. O directamente usar el retorno de ObtenerDatosDeLaInterfaz() y quitar el NuevoEvento:

```
$('#btnAgregar').click(function() { //Cuando el usuario presiona el botón agrega la información
  EnviarInformacion('agregar', ObtenerDatosDeLaInterfaz());
});

function ObtenerDatosDeLaInterfaz() {
  return {
    id_usuarios: $('#id_usuarios').val(),
    selectUsuarios: $('#selectUsuarios').val(),
    //Mostrar la información del evento en los inputs
    title: $('#title').val(),
    start: $('#fecha').val() + " " + $('#hora').val(),
    end: $('#fecha').val() + " " + $('#hora').val(),
    color: $('#color').val(),
    textColor: "#FFFFFF" ,//Color por defecto que agregara el boton agregar
    descripcion: $('#descripcion').val()  
  };
}
```

Comment: gracias ya conseguí que me insertara un saludo !